# Yii2 asset manager extra files and style include

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, less, yii2

I wanted to include a custom bootstrap template compiled from less, so I added this entries to web.php config:

```
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => '@app/assets/less',
                'css' => ['bootstrap.less']
            ],
        ],
```

The file is compiled and is ok. But I have to problems:

The original bootstrap css files are also copied (which is not a big deal, but at a high load I think it could be an unnecessary plus). I have a few .less file in the directory where my bootstrap.less is located, those files are also copied.

Is there a way to disable copying these files? (I am using Yii2 basic)